# 'no application named forms found in the server' error

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

when I try to run forms in oracle forms builder, the browser prints an error 'no application named forms found in the server'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaFYo.png)

Comment: Which version of Forms are you using?

Comment: version 10.12.0.2

Comment: I attached an image showing the error in the topic

Comment: Are you really using Netscape Navigator?

Comment: yes and I also tried with google chrome and internet explorer

Comment: Did you start OC4J instance?

Comment: yes, I started it